# Little code from O'Really, can you explain? (grep, ls, pipe)

Tags: bash, function, grep, cut, ls

I quote the "Learning the Bash Shell" book:

"Here is a function that allows you to list all files that were
last modified on the date you give as argument:"

```
function lsd
{
date=$1
ls -l | grep -i "^.\{42\}$date" | cut -c55-
}
```

But to me return null to screen. Can someone explain me what happens in code contained in " ", and why doesn't work? Thank you all

Comment: The text inside the quotes is a regular expression.  `grep` matches it to its input.  To debug something like this, play around with the command, removing parts, changing parts, etc. until you understand what each part does.  I would suggest first simplifying it to `ls -l | cut -c55 -`.  Then try `ls -l | grep . | cut -c55-`.  Then try `ls -l | grep foo | cut -c55-`.  Continue experimenting until you have a better understanding of what's happening.

Comment: try executing each part separately and see what it returns.